# MySQL multidirectional ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, time, timestamp

I have a table with the column 'time' which stores timestamps. I want to order it so that if the timestamp is in the future (ie. greater than what PHP's time() function returns), it orders it ascending. If it is not in the future, order it descending in value.

EDIT:
Suppose I had this list of timestamps (I know they're not actual ones, but for simplicity's sake):

```
1896
779
468
1478
846
1384
```

Then supppose the current timestamp is '1000'. The list should be reordered by the query to look something like this:

```
1384
1478
1896
846
779
468
```

So effectively all the data above 1000 is sorted ASC, and all data below is sorted DESC.

Comment: please post with some sample data and output format how you need?

Comment: is it unclear? I'll edit my post...

Comment: Do one query for the future times with ascending order, a second query for past times with descending order, and combine them with `UNION`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put an expression in the `ORDER BY`:

```
 ORDER BY ts >= NOW() DESC, (ts >= NOW()) * ts ASC, ts DESC
```

Booleans conditions are returned as 0 or 1 in MySQL.

Thus all the future timestamps are ordered `1 DESC, timestamp ASC, [timestamp DESC]` and the past timestamps are ordered `0 DESC, 0 ASC, timestamp DESC` and you get the desired order.

This would save you repeating predicates, but would probably hamper performance.

Comment: +1, at this point I like your answer more than I like mine, it is an elegant solution. I don't know if there are any performance penalties for doing this, but it is clearly way nicer

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can sort the same query by the same columns in two different ways, but the same result might be achieved by doing this in two steps. You can either run two separate queries and merge the results or another option would be to use an **UNION**

Let's say you now have:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `timestamp`
```

You can rewrite it as:

```
(
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        `table` 
    ORDER BY 
        `timestamp` DESC 
    WHERE 
        timestamp < NOW()
) 
UNION ALL 
(
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        `table` 
    ORDER BY 
        `timestamp` ASC 
    WHERE timestamp >= NOW()
)
```

Comment: `:current` should be `NOW()`?

Comment: @Barmar righ, it might be the result of the NOW() function. I added it like this because the question is also tagged as PHP, not only as MySQL and I figured that chances are that PDO might be used and those could be bound parameters. Maybe at some point in the future this would be needed for an arbitrary point in time, not just from the current timestamp from the MySQL server's point of view.

Comment: @Barmar but you are right, considering the question, NOW() might be a better idea, I'll edit the answer. Thank you for that.

Comment: I'd be tempted to use `UNION ALL` here as you know that there won't be any dupes.. thus saving the engine a check. Also +1 as this may be faster than my solution under certain conditions.

Comment: @Arth you are right, as long as the equality is treated in only one of the two queries I'm guessing that there won't be any duplicates. Thank you for the addition.